# How to get Pareto IV parameter estimates

Tags: r, estimation, pareto-distribution

I have a serie with 850 observations, and I need to fit the Pareto IV distribution. How could I do this in R?

I read the guide VGAM, however, I'm not  able to run it.

If anyone knows, please provide me with a detailed (step by step) answer so that I can understand it...

Answer (score 3):

First install package `VGAM`. After instalation, use `library` command to load it. Then fit and estimate like this:

```
> library(VGAM)
> #Generating a sample data
> pdata <- data.frame(y = rparetoIV(2000, scale = exp(1),ineq = exp(-0.3), shape = exp(1)))
> #Fitting paretoIV
> fit <- vglm(y ~ 1, paretoIV, data = pdata, trace = TRUE)
VGLM    linear loop  1 :  loglikelihood = -4458.70611
VGLM    linear loop  2 :  loglikelihood = -4016.73751
VGLM    linear loop  3 :  loglikelihood = -3649.98206
VGLM    linear loop  4 :  loglikelihood = -3638.00816
VGLM    linear loop  5 :  loglikelihood = -3295.17245
VGLM    linear loop  6 :  loglikelihood = -2950.35959
VGLM    linear loop  7 :  loglikelihood = -2899.05851
VGLM    linear loop  8 :  loglikelihood = -2888.96505
VGLM    linear loop  9 :  loglikelihood = -2888.71811
VGLM    linear loop  10 :  loglikelihood = -2888.71723
VGLM    linear loop  11 :  loglikelihood = -2888.71723
> coef(fit, matrix = TRUE)
            log(scale) log(inequality) log(shape)
(Intercept)   1.043666      -0.3020726   1.023722
> #Extracting coefficinets
> Coef(fit)
     scale inequality      shape 
 2.8396070  0.7392844  2.7835358 
> #summary of the fit
> summary(fit)

Call:
vglm(formula = y ~ 1, family = paretoIV, data = pdata, trace = TRUE)

Pearson residuals:
                      Min         1Q    Median      3Q    Max
log(scale)       -8.25407 -0.8617977 -0.328181 0.76683 4.4188
log(inequality)  -0.82645 -0.7260530 -0.378008 0.41872 7.1240
log(shape)      -17.23069  0.0058047  0.081766 0.15972 4.4172

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error  z value
(Intercept):1  1.04367    0.14834   7.0358
(Intercept):2 -0.30207    0.03012 -10.0291
(Intercept):3  1.02372    0.14190   7.2145

Number of linear predictors:  3 

Names of linear predictors: log(scale), log(inequality), log(shape)

Dispersion Parameter for paretoIV family:   1

Log-likelihood: -2888.717 on 5997 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations: 11 
>
```

I took above codes form package [VGAM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/VGAM.pdf), page 493. You need to replace your data with pdata.

Comment: I had already read this guide on VGAM, the thing I do not understand is if I have to generate the data with these parameters of the example or not. if not, what should I use?

Comment: I didn't have your data .... right? So I had to generate a sample from a Pareto IV distribution using rparetoIV. Therefore, the answer is no ... you don't have to generate with these parameters. You just need to create a data frame using your own observations like this : `pdata.new <- data.frame(y =c(obs.1,obs.2, ...., obs.850))`. Then use this new data frame to fit i.e. `fit.new <- vglm(y ~ 1, paretoIV, data = pdata.new, trace = TRUE)`